# Better generic binary search tree in C++

Tags: c++, tree, c++17

### Introduction

This is a follow-up to my [previous question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/195767/93301). This code rocks new ground-up implementation of core functionality, which I made from combining @vnp’s and @JDługosz's answers. The core functionality got ~100 LOC decrease and insert gained 15-25% performance gain. It turns out that my remove tests didn't test anything at all in the previous version (now fixed), so I don't know how much performance was gained in remove, but I'm pretty sure the gain is paramount.

Though there are some changes I didn't make. I state the reasons closer to the end of post.

**Changes:**

- Uniform node location

There is a single function to find the desired node with value or yet to be value. This is achieved through double pointers. Yes, double pointers.

- Using boolean conversion instead of `== nullptr`
- Using default initialization of members

**New functionality:**

- SFINAE

`try_insert` is now uniform for both rvalue and lvalue, and activated only if type is either copyable or moveable. Copy constructor checks for feature too.

- Copy constructor
- emplace

This one was a little bit tricky to pull out. It had some exception issues, but should be okay. The only thing that makes me worried is alignment, though I guess doing SSE or some other hardware trick on BSTs is pretty much useless.

- size

Now the tree knows its size and correctly maintains it.

---

### Code

```
#ifndef ALGORITHMS_BINARY_SEARCH_TREE_HPP
#define ALGORITHMS_BINARY_SEARCH_TREE_HPP

#include "binary_tree_iterator.hpp"
#include <ostream>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>
#include <memory>

namespace shino
{
    template <typename ValueType>
    class binary_search_tree
    {
        constexpr static bool v_copiable = std::is_copy_constructible_v<ValueType>;
        constexpr static bool v_moveable = std::is_move_constructible_v<ValueType>;
        struct node
        { //DO NOT MOVE ELEMENTS AROUND, emplace relies on this order
            const ValueType value;
            node* left = nullptr;
            node* right = nullptr;
        };

        node* root = nullptr;
        std::size_t element_count = 0;
    public:
        using iterator = binary_tree_iterator<node>;

        binary_search_tree(binary_search_tree&& other) noexcept:
                root(std::exchange(other.root, nullptr)),
                element_count(std::exchange(other.element_count, 0))
        {}

        binary_search_tree& operator=(binary_search_tree&& other) noexcept
        {
            std::swap(root, other.root);
            std::swap(element_count, other.element_count);
            return *this;
        }

        template <typename = std::enable_if_t<v_copiable>>
        explicit binary_search_tree(const binary_search_tree& other)
        {
            if (other.element_count == 0)
                return;
            root = new node(other.root->value);
            deep_copy(root->left, other.root->left);
            deep_copy(root->right, other.root->right);

            element_count = other.element_count;
        }

        template <typename AnotherType,
                  typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<ValueType, std::decay_t<AnotherType>>
                                                     and (v_copiable || v_moveable)>>
        bool try_insert(AnotherType&& value)
        {
            auto insertion_point = find_node(value);
            if (*insertion_point)
                return false;
            *insertion_point = new node{std::forward<AnotherType>(value)};
            ++element_count;
            return true;
        }

        template <typename ... Args>
        bool emplace(Args&& ... args)
        {
            std::unique_ptr<char[]> buffer = std::make_unique<char[]>(sizeof(node));
            new (buffer.get()) node(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
            auto possible_node = reinterpret_cast<node*>(buffer.get());
            auto insertion_point = find_node(possible_node->value);
            if (*insertion_point)
            {
                std::destroy_at(possible_node->value);
                return false;
            }

            possible_node->left = nullptr;
            possible_node->right = nullptr;
            *insertion_point = possible_node;
            buffer.release();
            ++element_count;
            return true;
        }

        bool exists(const ValueType& value) const
        {
            return *find_node(value) != nullptr;
        }

        bool delete_if_exists(const ValueType& value)
        {
            if (element_count == 0)
                return false;

            auto child_ptr = find_node(value);
            if (!*child_ptr)
                return false;

            *child_ptr = find_replacement(*child_ptr);
            --element_count;
            return true;
        }

        std::size_t size() const {
            return element_count;
        }

        void clear()
        {
            clear_helper(root);
        }

        iterator begin()
        {
            return iterator{root};
        }

        iterator end()
        {
            return {};
        }

        ~binary_search_tree()
        {
            clear();
        }

    private:
        void deep_copy(node* dest, node* source)
        {
            if (!source)
                return;

            if (source->left)
            {
                dest->left = new node(source->left->value);
                deep_copy(dest->left, source->left);
            }

            if (source->right)
            {
                dest->right = new node(source->right->value);
                deep_copy(dest->right, source->right);
            }
        }

        node* find_replacement(node* start_pos)
        {
            if (!start_pos->left)
            {
                auto replacement = start_pos->right;
                delete start_pos;
                return replacement;
            }

            auto descendant = start_pos->left;
            while (descendant->right)
                descendant = descendant->right;

            descendant->right = start_pos->right;
            delete start_pos;
            return start_pos->left;
        }

        void clear_helper(node* start_position)
        {
            if (!start_position)
                return;
            clear_helper(start_position->left);
            clear_helper(start_position->right);

            delete start_position;
        }

        node** find_node(const ValueType& value)
        {
            auto* current = &root;
            while (*current and (*current)->value != value)
                if (value < (*current)->value)
                    current = &(*current)->left;
                else
                    current = &(*current)->right;

            return current;
        }
    };
}

#endif //ALGORITHMS_BINARY_SEARCH_TREE_HPP
```

### Tests:

```
#include "binary_search_tree.hpp"

#include <random>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>


std::vector<int> generate_unique_numbers(std::size_t size)
{
    std::vector<int> result;
    if (size == 0)
        return {};

    static std::mt19937_64 twister;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> distribution{0, static_cast<int>(size - 1)};

    std::unordered_set<int> numbers;
    while (numbers.size() != size)
    {
        numbers.insert(distribution(twister));
    }

    return {numbers.begin(), numbers.end()};
}

void run_randomized_insert_tests()
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i <= 5'000; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "running binary_search_tree insert test on size " << i << '\n';
        auto numbers = generate_unique_numbers(i);
        shino::binary_search_tree<int> tree;
        for (auto x: numbers)
            tree.try_insert(x);

        std::sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end());
        std::size_t numbers_index = 0;
        for (auto x: tree)
        {
            if (x != numbers[numbers_index++])
                throw std::logic_error{"tree binary_tree_iterator is broken on size " + std::to_string(i)};
        }
    }
}

void remove_value(std::vector<int>& vec, int x)
{
    vec.erase(std::remove(vec.begin(), vec.end(), x), vec.end());
}

void run_randomized_remove_tests()
{
    static std::mt19937_64 twister;

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i <= 1'000; ++i)
    {
        shino::binary_search_tree<int> tree;
        auto numbers = generate_unique_numbers(i);
        for (auto x: numbers)
            tree.try_insert(x);
        std::sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end());
        std::cout << "running remove test on tree of size " << i << '\n';
        for (std::size_t j = 0; j < i; ++j)
        {
            std::bernoulli_distribution dist;
            if (dist(twister))
            {
                tree.delete_if_exists(static_cast<int>(j));
                remove_value(numbers, static_cast<int>(j));
            }

        }
        std::size_t values_index = 0;
        for (auto x: tree)
        {
            if (numbers[values_index] != x)
                throw std::logic_error{"remove doesn't work correctly on " + std::to_string(i)};
            ++values_index;
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    std::cout << "running randomized insert tests...\n";
    run_randomized_insert_tests();
    std::cout << "randomized insert tests passed successfully\n";

    std::cout << "running randomized remove tests...\n";
    run_randomized_remove_tests();
    std::cout << "randomized remove tests passed successfully\n";
}
```

---

### Not applied changes

- Return iterator along with insert

I don't think I have suitable iterator interface to implement at the moment. `shino::binary_tree_iterator` mentioned in [this post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/195919/generic-in-order-traversal-iterator-for-binary-trees) might hinder the performance of those operations.

- Still using `!= nullptr` in `exists`

Linter was arguing that implicit conversion in that context is confusing. I gave in.

---

### Concerns

Mostly I'd like to improve simplicity and readability of the code on this iteration, and improve usage of standard library. Though if you see any low hanging performance fruit, please let me know. As always, any other comments are welcome too.

Comment: I'd like this to reach boost level of quality. I wanted to apply for GSoC, but couldn't pass their coding test. I'm starting preparations for the next year already :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Memory management

- `clear` and `deep_copy` might overflow the callstack for large number of nodes if the tree is highly unbalanced.
- Prefer `std::unique_ptr` over raw owning pointers. `binary_search_tree::root`, `node::left` and `node::right` can easily be replaced with `std::unique_ptr<node>` without impeding performance. Doing so easily documents the ownership of `node`s, thus increasing readability.
- `emplace` just tramples all over alignment requirements, as `alignof(node)` (depending on `alignof(ValueType)`) might be much greater than `alignof(char)`. What prevents a forwarding contructor in `node`, like this one:

  ```
  template<typename... Args, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible_v<ValueType, Args...>>>
  node(Args&&... args)
    : value{std::forward<Args>(args)...} {}
  ```

  Using this constructor would simplify the code in `emplace`.
- `find_replacement` accesses `start_pos->left` after deleting `start_pos`.

## Correctness

- `emplace` doesn't check whether `ValueType` would be constructible from the passed `Args`.
- `try_insert` will accept an lvalue reference to a move-only type, or an rvalue reference to a copy-only type.

## Performance

- Balancing the tree would decrease the worst-case insertion, lookup and deletion costs from \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$ to \$\mathcal{O}(\log n)\$. However, it might increase the average runtime by a constant factor. As always with performance: Measure, measure, measure!
- Trees are notoriously bad regarding cache misses because of all the cache misses due to pointer chasing. Maybe using an arena allocator (aka "object pool" or "region allocator") could help to reduce those cache misses.

## Interface

- Which traversal order is used by the iterators? The naming doesn't clarify whether it's using in-order, pre-order, post-order, level-order or some different traversal order.
- Rule of 5 violation: copy assignment operator is missing and not declared as deleted.
- Many member function return a `bool` to indicate whether an operation did some specific work. This usually doesn't matter, as the result would be the same. If it does matter in some case, the relevant information can usually be checked in another way,
- Many member function names deviate from the usual standard library ones. This might lead to confusion, and requires users of the library to add adaptors if they want to use standard library functionality, e.g. algorithms.
- `find_node` will never return a `nullptr`, so the implementation could be adjusted to return a `node*&` (basically, exchange the loop for recursion). This would allow clearer code, as it removes the need for the obscure `(*pos)->value` syntax (replacement would be `pos->value`).

## `template` restrictions

- Prefer error messages with `static_assert` over SFINAE if a (member) function has no overloads. This helps with debugging and gives better error messages. (SFINAE is still fine if other overloads might be a better fit, as it only removes that candidate from the overload set.)
- Non-templated functions are always a better match than templated function, so the default copy constructor will always be a better match than the templated one. To get a conditional copy constructor, the condition needs to be evaluated at class level (e.g. by inheriting from a dependent base class).

Comment: I once tried implementing it with smart pointers, but it quickly became irritating. Though may be I’m used them incorrectly.

Comment: @Incomputable: So, this should be it. I did some tinkering, you can see the results [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/8gSAtrvgVFKqlWic).

Comment: @Incomputable: Well, just worked on it a bit while finding all those issues ;) Also, forgot to note: For copy construction and copy assignment operators to work with `std::for_each` the iterators would need to go level-order or pre-order. Otherwise the resulting internal representation might differ.

Answer (score 1):

Why:

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> buffer = std::make_unique<char[]>(sizeof(node));
new (buffer.get()) node(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
auto possible_node = reinterpret_cast<node*>(buffer.get());
```

Is this not easier to write?

```
std::unique_ptr<node> node = std::make_unique<node>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
auto possible_node = node.get();
```

Comment: I don't know to be honest. My mind jammed for a bit, as I started writing the code late at night. I guess it is another indication to stop the bad habit.

Comment: That would require a `node` constructor accepting those forwarded arguments (see my answer). Without that, your next-best choice would be `std::make_unique<node>(ValueType{std::forward<Args>(args)...})`, but that won't work if `ValueType` has no copy constructor and no move constructor (which, sadly, is one of the reasons `emplace` exists in the first place).

Comment: @hoffmale: We already know he has a constructor that works. Because the second line is a new statement passing exactly those parameters to the constructor!

Comment: @MartinYork: You mean `new (buffer.get()) node(std::forward<Args>(args)...);`? That doesn't call any existing constructor, it tries to use aggregate initialization, which will fail unless `Args...` somehow is convertible to `ValueType`, `ValueType, node*` or `ValueType, node*, node*`.

Comment: Eh, wait, I misread those parentheses as braces. Sry for that. It calls a non-existing constructor unless `Args` is empty. So it might or might not compile, depending on what you're calling `emplace` with.

Comment: @hoffmale So if the original compiles then my alternative compiles. If the original does not compile then my alternative does not compile. I don't see the issue.

Comment: @hoffmale and Loki, would you mind if I quickly update the post? Otherwise it seems off-topic. I thought I did test it once, but probably the whole thing somehow escaped my attention. I got too focused on exception handling and risky buffer manipulation.

Comment: @Incomputable: Don't update the code in the question. At the time you posted it, it was working to the best of your knowledge ;) If every question that contains a bug were off-topic, we'd barely have any left.